# Composition: can container exist without one of its contained object? JAVA

Tags: java, composition

What is composition?

- A: When the container object get "destroyed" all of his composed
  objects are destroyed.
- B: When one of the composed object get destroyed, the container will
  get destroyed too.

---

Example:

```
class Car {      
    Engine engine = new Engine();
}
```

if i destroy the Car, the engine will get destroyed too (point A).
But if i destroy the engine, the car will exist even without an engine, is this still composition (point B)?

Are both points (A and B) right? or A is the only one.

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy"? Garbage collection?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, if i do car.engine = null;(point B) or i put the reference variable of Car to null, carReference = null; (Point A)

Comment: But what has this to do with composition?

Comment: As long as you have a reference to an object, it won't be garbage-collected. If you set the engine to null with not other references the engine is gone. You'll have a Car object with no engine. If you set the Car object to null, then both the car and engine will be gc'd.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson   It was an example, i was studying composition, i tried to google but i found nothing. I just want to know if composition means that when contained class doesn't exist the container class exist, because my teacher says so.

Comment: Composition simply refers to the encapsulation of classes within another. It doesn't dictate their lifecycle; that's just plain Java GC semantics

Comment: @OneCricketeer then theres no difference with aggregation, it is just the encapsualtion of classes within another,  how can  i say the relationship is aggregation or composition

Comment: The shown code is composition

Comment: I know, but why it is not aggregation, because Engine can exist only with Car in this case? or because if Car is destroyed (lost reference) engine will get destroyed too

Comment: + can i use Engine type in other classes too or i lose the composition.